# Export Gridview Records to Text File Using ASP.Net C#

Tags: asp.net

Export Gridview Records to Text File Using ASP.Net C#..

Plz follow this link.,
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/export-gridview-records-to-text-file/ ..

Plz Solve This Problem.Follow it.
when we convert export gridview to textformat when an output will come into textfile those file data will save into particular server folder.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking or what the problem is. Please clarify.

Comment: What is the error/issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing below `Response.Write` you would want to append it to text file using `File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt", Rowbind.ToString())`;

```
 Response.Output.Write(Rowbind.ToString());  
 Response.Flush();  
 Response.End();
```

Reference on how to write text file is on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/8bh11f1k.aspx).